# Remove drop shadow from Fancybox 2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Is there a way to remove the drop shadow on Fancybox  2?  Is there a CSS solution? I spent forever trying various solutions with CSS and trying to hack the JS but nothing seems to work. Please help. Here is how I am calling Fancybox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function(){
   this.title = $(this.element).next('.newTitle').html();
  },
        padding: 0, 
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',

        prevEffect: 'fade',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        closeBtn   : false,
        arrows : false,
        helpers: {
            title   : { type : 'outside' },
            buttons: {},
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.5)'
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following in the fancybox css

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

to

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

or you remove it from fancybox css. And of course you can add the second snippet to other css files.

Comment: Well, normally it's not a good idea to modify the original files. It would be better to add this rule in your custom css file AND after including the fancybox css file.

Comment: @JFK You are absolutely right. That makes a return to the original state much easier.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I put it in my site CSS and it works. I also think Barbara was right but I checked Paul's answer because it helped a novice like me.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: JFK pointed out that my notes were on the wrong version of fancy box.
For fancybox2 the dropshadow is on

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

override this to set the box-shadow : none

Comment: You could override these rules in your custom css file AND after including the fancybox css file.